# What is shortcut to SharePoint site URL

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, url, promoted-links

I am using SharePoint online. I have 20pages and each pages having Promoted Links web part (Tile view). I have hard coded site URL in Promoted Links web part.

Now, I have to setup UAT environment. My approach is to update site URL which is hardcoded and update with UAT site URLs. Means - Open each web part in UAT and update site URLs.

Is there any better way I can do this?

I remember using "~site" in PowerShell which takes site URL where PowerShell runs. Is there anything in this case?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**No**. You cannot use tokens like `~site` in hyperlink column URLs.

You have to either provide complete absolute URL like `https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/UAT/SitePages/A.aspx` OR relative URL like `/sites/UAT/SitePages/A.aspx`.

Comment: Hi @Chintan, does this answer your question? If yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.